# how to use wildcard in replace string?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I need to change all:

```
<label for="*">
```

into

```
<label for="*" class="inline checkbox">
```

But it turns out all my `<label for="XXXXXX">` were turned into `<label for="*" class="inline checkbox">`. Yes, the `*` is literally kept as a string not as a wildcard.

How come the wildcard is only effective in Find not in Replace? What should I input in the Replace string?

Comment: You've seen this right? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/afy96z92%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Are you using String.Replace or Regex.Replace? Can you show your code?

Comment: @Forte L. I am not using any code. Just the Find and Replace dialog box.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a way to do this with wildcards, but you can get it done using regular expressions:

1. In the `Find and Replace` dialog box, below `Find Options`, check
   `Use:` and from the dropdown select `Regular expressions`.
2. In the text box for `Find What`, type: `\<label for="{.*}"\>`
3. In the text box for `Replace with`, type: `<label for="\1"
   class="inline checkbox">`

Notes:

- I escaped `<` and `>` with `\` because they are special characters.
- `.*` will match any string.
- In the replace text, `\1` will replace with the string found between
  the `{}` in the find expression.

Also, if you click the arrows next to the find and replace text boxes, you will find more info about the special characters.

Answer (score 29):

The accepted answer is offered in other places as well but didn't work for me.

I had to use (.*) in the Find and $1 in the Replace.

Comment: I think it changed in VS 13 or 15.  I'm using VS 15 and can vouch for the same thing.  {} no longer work but () do.  Same with identifying groups with $

Comment: Same applies for VS2017

Comment: This answer applies to VS Code as well if anyone in the future is wondering.

Comment: Working in VSC as of January 2021, just make sure to toggle the regex button in the find menu